# Easily populate HTML forms from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've seen this HTML notation on blogs but they don't mention how to use it:

```
<input name="object[property]" value=""/>
```

How is it called and how do you take advantage of it? 
Do I need a templating engine? can jquery populate a form automatically if I provide the JSON object?

Note: I've seen that when I post my form, it provide me the bundling of all the data in a js object. My question  is more on the initialisation of the form itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-arrays-with-html-form-inputs

If you do...

```
<input type="text" name="object[title]" value="Mr.">
<input type="text" name="object[first_name]" value="First Name">
<input type="text" name="object[last_name]" value="Last Name">
```

...and send the form as-is, your server-side POST variables will look like this:

```
//PHP
echo $_POST[object][title]; // echo "Mr."
echo $_POST[object][first_name]; // echo "First Name"
echo $_POST[object][last_name]; // echo "LastName"
```

Even if you have a JSON object defined, you still need ***something*** to fill up your form with default values. (such as a templating engine or straight JS)

```
var JSON = {
    title: 'Mr.',
    first_name: 'First Name',
    last_name: 'Last Name'
}

for (a in JSON) {
    document.write('<input type="text" name="object[' + a + ']" value="' + JSON[a] + '">')
}​
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/2cBQB/1/

Comment: AHHHH! `document.write` run away!

Comment: Haha, I know, it's really ugly. It was only to explain the example, I swear!

Comment: Create the element using the DOM: `var input = document.createElement("input"); input.setAttribute("type", "text"); input.setAttribute("name", "object[" + a + "]"); input.setAttribute("value", JSON[a]);`

Answer (score 1):

That is used for sending an array of values to the server.  For example, if you have 10 inputs with the name "foo[]"  then in php you can say $_POST['foo'] (or get respectively)  for an array of the values

Answer (score 1):

You use that find of format when you want the result to be available as an associative array in the script to which data from this form was submitted. In PHP, you would then be able to access the value of the above element as: $_POST["object"]["properly"]. It is useful in grouping together related form inputs (like date+month+year).